# ¿Cómo filtrar una columna de marco de datos por fecha?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, dataframe

Tengo un conjunto de datos que utilizo para el aprendizaje automático. Sin embargo, quiero dividir mi conjunto de datos en conjunto de entrenamiento y conjunto de prueba. Le gustaria que el conjunto de entrenamiento debe estar hecho de todos los préstamos emitidos hasta septiembre. Mi `test` incluiria entonces el resto (es decir, Q4-Oct, Nov, Dec). ¿Cómo puedo preparar el conjunto de datos de la forma que considere más adecuada para esta tarea?

```
    issue_d int_rate    installment dti revol_bal   revol_util  inq_last_6mths  delinq_2yrs pub_rec loan_status purpose_credit_card purpose_debt_consolidation  purpose_home_improvement    purpose_house   purpose_major_purchase  purpose_medical purpose_moving  purpose_other   purpose_renewable_energy    purpose_small_business  purpose_vacation    purpose_wedding
11  Mar-2018    14.07%  233.05  24.69   707 15.7%   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16  Mar-2018    11.98%  232.44  20.25   5004    36% 0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17  Mar-2018    26.77%  607.97  24.40   7364    46% 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  Mar-2018    20.39%  560.94  15.76   14591   34.2%   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
23  Mar-2018    7.34%   930.99  16.18   755 0%  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
...
130741  Apr-2018    6.07%   309.85  14.64   17380   24.5%   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
130742  Apr-2018    11.98%  555.86  21.05   19591   20.5%   2   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
130744  Apr-2018    11.98%  215.84  14.68   4707    37.7%   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

El typo de `issue_d` es `object`.

Hasta ahora no me preocupa de las fechas utilisando :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, random_state=123, stratify=y)
```

## Annex : para reproducir la dataframe

Pueden descargar el csv [aquí](https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action) (préstamos bancarios para 2018. Se dividen en cuatro trimestres). Usando Python 3 se puede obtener haciendo:

```
import pandas as pd 
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
data_Q1 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q1.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q2 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q3 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q4 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
frames = [data_Q1,data_Q2,data_Q3,data_Q4]

result = pd.concat(frames)
subset = result.loc[result["loan_status"].isin(['Charged Off','Fully Paid'])]
```

Comment: Una observación (no se si es un error a copiar el código), `data_Q2`, `data_Q3` y `data_Q4` usan el mismo archivo csv, `"LoanStats_2018Q2.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes muchas posibilidades:

- Dado que `test` va a ser el contenido de `data_Q4` (cuarto trimestre), una opción muy simple es crear una columna que identifque el trimestre:

  ```
  import io
  import pandas as pd

  import pandas as pd 
  # Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
  data_Q1 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q1.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
  data_Q2 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
  data_Q3 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q3.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
  data_Q4 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q4.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')

  data_Q1["quarter"] = "Q1"
  data_Q2["quarter"] = "Q2"
  data_Q3["quarter"] = "Q3"
  data_Q4["quarter"] = "Q4"

  frames = [data_Q1,data_Q2, data_Q3, data_Q4]
  result = pd.concat(frames)

  bool_filter = result["quarter"] == "Q4"
  test = result[bool_filter]
  training = result[~bool_filter]
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> training["issue_d"].unique()
  > ['Mar-2018' 'Feb-2018' 'Jan-2018' 'Jun-2018' 'May-2018' 'Apr-2018'
  >  'Sep-2018' 'Aug-2018' 'Jul-2018']
  > >>> test["issue_d"].unique())
  > ['Dec-2018' 'Nov-2018' 'Oct-2018']
  > ```
- Otra opción es simplemente filtrar usando un filtro boleano sobre la columna `issue_d`:

  ```
  bool_filter = result["issue_d"].isin(['Dec-2018', 'Nov-2018', 'Oct-2018'])
  test = result[bool_filter]
  training = result[~bool_filter]
  ```
- Hacer la columna de tipo categórico sería otra posibilidad:

  ```
  months= ['Jan-2018', 'Feb-2018', 'Mar-2018', 'Apr-2018', 'May-2018', 'Jun-2018',
           'Jul-2018', 'Aug-2018', 'Sep-2018', 'Oct-2018', 'Nov-2018' ,'Dec-2018']

  result["issue_d"] = pd.Categorical( result["issue_d"], categories=months, ordered=True)
  test = result[result["issue_d"] >= 'Oct-2018']
  training = result[result["issue_d"] < 'Oct-2018']
  ```
- Por último, la forma más directa y general es convertir la columna `issue_d` a tipo `datetime` y luego simplemente seleccionar usando intervalos de fechas:

  ```
  result["issue_d"] = pd.to_datetime(result["issue_d"], format='%b-%Y')
  test = result[result["issue_d"] >= 'Oct-2018']
  training = result[result["issue_d"] < 'Oct-2018']
  test["issue_d"].unique()
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> test.shape
  > (366830, 144)
  >
  > >>> test["issue_d"].unique()
  > array(['2018-12-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-11-01T00:00:00.000000000',
  >        '2018-10-01T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
  >
  > >>> training.shape
  > (366830, 144)
  >
  > >>> training["issue_d"].unique()
  > array(['2018-03-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-02-01T00:00:00.000000000',
  >        '2018-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-06-01T00:00:00.000000000',
  >        '2018-05-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-04-01T00:00:00.000000000',
  >        '2018-09-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-08-01T00:00:00.000000000',
  >        '2018-07-01T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
  > ```